# merging multiple arrays together giving error

Tags: python, arrays, list

I am trying to merge arrays like following code:

```
import numpy as np

from numpy import column_stack as column_stack
from matplotlib.pyplot import plot as plot
from matplotlib.pyplot import show as show

N = 120
Yq = np.arange(0,N-1)

YY = Yq[N//2:]-N + Yq +  Yq[:N//2]+N
#YY = column_stack( (Yq[N//2:]-2*PI, Yq, Yq[:N//2]+2*PI))

plot(YY)
show()
```

I tried `'+'` and `column_stack()`, but neither works. How do I make it work to merge three arrays? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to use is `numpy.concatenate()`, not `numpy.column_stack()`:

```
YY = numpy.concatenate( (Yq[N//2:]-2*PI, Yq, Yq[:N//2]+2*PI))
```

Comment: @NickXTsui Great. Please upvote/accept if you are happy with the answer.